# How to make columns auto wrap to new row/line

Tags: php, html, css

I have a script that runs a query and retruns a number of records. I then need to display each record in table columns across the screen. when the right hand side of the screen is reached wrap the next column on to a new row/line.

I have read that this can be done putting each column inside a Div with a "display: inline-block" CSS element.

An example of what I am trying to do can be seen here:

[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block)

How can I reprodue this using my code below.

My code:
CSS

```
.gridview_inline_block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

My page code:

```
echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='2'>";

while ($row_Audit = mysql_fetch_assoc($Audit)) {
$RoomNo1 = $row_Audit['HistRoom'];
$RoomNo2 = $row_Audit['ValidRoom'];
$UniqueID = $row_Audit['UniqueID'];
$UniqueID2 = $row_Audit['ValidUniqueID'];

if($row_Audit['OutOfService'] == 1) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo " <div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td id=\"room\" class=\"roomviewOutofService\">
        <a href='13-1-room_edit_status_iframe.php?Room=$RoomNo2' target='_self'>$RoomNo2</a>
    </td></div>";

}elseif($row_Audit['ValidStatus']== 6 ) {
    echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td id=\"room\"  class=\"roomviewsaved\">
        <a href='15-1-3-room_report_saved_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID2' target='_self'>$RoomNo2</a>
    </td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['HistStatus']== 1 || $row_Audit['PassFail']== 1 && $row_Audit['RepairCode']!= 4) {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td  id=\"room\" class=\"compfaults\">
    <a href='52-1-room_report_faults_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID' target='_self'>$RoomNo1</a>
</td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['HistStatus']== 2 || !empty($row_Audit['RepairDate'])) {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td  id=\"room\" class=\"compfixed\">
    <a href='13-1-4-by_room_repaired_report_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID' target='_self'>$RoomNo1</a>
</td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['PassFail']== 1 && $row_Audit['ValidStatus']!= 6) {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td  id=\"room\" class=\"compfaults\">
    <a href='14-1-room_report_faults_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID' target='_self'>$RoomNo1</a>
</td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['ValidStatus']== 8) {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td id=\"room\"  class=\"roomviewmagentalight\">
    <a href='13-1-5-room_report_due_all1_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID' target='_self'>$RoomNo2</a>
</td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['Status']== 5) {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td  id=\"room\" class=\"roomviewmagenta\">
    <a href='room_report_due_all2_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID&OverDue=1' target='_self'>$RoomNo2</a>
</td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['ValidStatus']== 7  ) {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td  id=\"room\" class=\"roomviewgreen\">
    <a href='14-1-5-room_report_complete_all_iframe.php?UniqueID=$UniqueID2' target='_self'>$RoomNo2</a>
</td></div>";

} elseif($row_Audit['ValidStatus'] === NULL || $row_Audit['ValidStatus'] == "" || $row_Audit['ValidStatus'] == "99") {
echo "<div  class=\"gridview_inline_block\"><td  id=\"room\" class=\"roomviewwhite\">
    $RoomNo2
</td></div>";
echo "</tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: You should start with valid html: You cannot have a `div` between the `tr` and the `td` tag.

Comment: you should share the html produced and css tried so far. something looks weird: table then tr then div ?!?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your feedback, I am going to reright the html.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the HTML and now I have only used DIV's and with the same CSS

```
<div class="floating-box">                              
<div class="roomviewsaved">
    <a href='test.php?UniqueID=<?php echo $UniqueID;?>' target='_self'><?php echo $RoomNo2;?></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for the input.